# existing activity into fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-2.2-froyo

I have created a tab fragments `in android 2.2` , with a `android compatibility support library` , now in my application i have few activities some of them are extends Activity class and some of them extends ListActivity.

so how can i convert the `existing Activity or ListActivity into Fragments` so that i can take the advantage of Fragment features ?

As to create a fragment , one has to extends Fragment class but if an activity is deriving ListActivity then what to do to convert it in a fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to review the `Fragment` documentation and samples on the [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). This will explain what a Fragment is able to do, and what you should be doing inside of your fragment.

In essence, its a very simple transition over to using Fragments once you have looked over the examples. You will need an Activity to contain the Fragments still.

To make this a lot simpler, I would advise you look into the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library, which will allow you to use the ActionBar and SupportLibrary back to 2.1.

To get you started, you will want to use the `Fragment` and `ListFragment` classes, which will be very similar to a standard activity, but the life cycles are a little different with a few naming changes.

Comment: Well in my ListView i got dialog box and all so there will be so much to change if i go for ListFragment , isnt it ?

Comment: You would think so... But not really :) I would suggest you create a new class, which extends from the Fragment, and start porting bit by bit. It will take you a bit of time initially, but the gains outweigh the time it takes :) Start with something simple like inflating the layout, and then make sure its loaded properly. Once this is done, then move onto the rest of your functionality.

Comment: No problem. I have been through the same issues, and its a much better experience once you have converted!

Answer (score 2):

You could try deriving it from [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)